Integral on the boundary of the unit disk
I want to calculate the following  integral
$$\int_{|x|=1} \frac{x^{\perp}}{|x|^a} dS(x)$$ where $x \in \mathbb{R}^2$.
My idea was to use a cut off function $$ p(|x|)\ge 0 for \; |x|\le 1$$ and $$p(|x|)=0 for \; |x|> 2$$ and do the following calculations
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^2} p(|x|) \frac{x^{\perp}}{|x|^a} dS(x)=\int_{|x|\le1} p(|x|)\frac{x^{\perp}}{|x|^a} dS(x)+\int_{|x|=1} p(|x|)\frac{x^{\perp}}{|x|^a} dS(x)$$
Then i think to do integration by parts on the first integral
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^2} p(|x|) \frac{x^{\perp}}{|x|^a} dS(x)=-c_a\int_{|x|\le1} \nabla^\perp p(|x|)\frac{1}{|x|^{a-1}} dx +\int_{|x|=1} p(|x|){|x|^{-a+1}} dS(x) +\int_{|x|=1} p(|x|)\frac{x^{\perp}}{|x|^a} dS(x)$$
But then i have no idea what to do.

On $\mathbb S^1$, the outward pointing unit normal is $\nu(x)=x$, so $x^\perp = (x \cdot \nu(x) )\nu(x) = x$. Hence, by odd symmetry $$ \int_{\mathbb S^1} \frac {x^\perp}{\vert x\vert^a} dS =  \int_{\mathbb S^1} x dS =0. $$

Its is not very clear for me how you go from the one integral to the other

On $\mathbb S^1$, (by definition) $\vert x \vert =1$, so $\frac{x^\perp}{\vert x\vert^a} = x^\perp$

Oh i see, thank you

You’re welcome :)
